# Hoping for clarification of this very basic explanation of the abc conjecture

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, abc-conjecture

An article online says:

> The abc conjecture refers to numerical expressions of the type $a + b = c$. The statement, which comes in several slightly different versions, concerns the prime numbers that divide each of the quantities $a$, $b$ and $c$. Every whole number, or integer, can be expressed in an essentially unique way as a product of prime numbers-- those that cannot be further factored out into smaller whole numbers: for example, $15 = 3 \times 5$ or $84 = 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 7$. In principle, the prime factors of a and b have no connection to those of their sum, c. But the abc conjecture links them together. It presumes, roughly, that if a lot of small primes divide a and b then only a few, large ones divide c.

My question related to this sentence therein:

> In principle, the prime factors of $a$ and $b$ have no connection to those of their sum, $c$.

I don't understand that statement, since $$c = (\text{the product of the prime factors of }a) + (\text{the product of the prime factors of }b).$$

That certainly *seems* like a connection!

I do not have strong math chops, and would appreciate an answer in English rather than in notation, to the extent possible. I fully realize I'm just not grasping what's being said, I'm certainly not critiquing the conjecture.

Comment: If the author had said "seemingly" there is no connection, that would have made more sense.

Comment: There is indeed the connection that you have stated; but in fact that's a very weak connection, because it turns out that adding numbers together is a very good way of destroying anything we know about their respective prime factorisations. (Except in the special case that they are both divisible by the same prime.) For instance, $2^5 + 3^3 = 59$ which is prime, even though both $2^5$ and $3^3$ are very much composite; whereas $2^{10} + 3^7 = 13^2 \times 19$ which makes a very *composite* number out of two other very composite numbers.

Comment: The relation $c = (\text{the product of the prime factors of }a) + (\text{the product of the prime factors of }b)$ gives zero information about the prime factors of $c$ (except in the trivial case when $a$ and $b$ have some common prime factors). The statement is not that the prime factors of $a$ and $b$ have no connection to $c$ but that the prime factors of aa and bb have no connection to the prime factors of $c$.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, the meaning of the statement

> In principle, the prime factors of $a$ and $b$ have no connection to those of their sum, $c$

is not that there does not exist any relation at all between them (we start by the assumption that $a+b=c$ as you have already mentioned in your post) but that there is no (yet known) deterministic relation between these prime factors. In other words, there is no (well not yet) statement, proposition, theory, algorithm that can give a full description of the prime factors of $c$, given the prime factors of $a$ and $b$.

**P.S.:** Apart from Mochizuki's recent developments of course.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that $a$ equals the product of its prime factors (and likewise for $b$), but that doesn't take into account multiplicity of factors. For example, the only prime factors of 72 are 2 and 3, but 72 is not $2\times 3$.

Even if you could get $c$ from just the prime factors of $a$ and $b$, that wouldn't tell you much about the prime factors of $c$ (and especially about their sizes) unless you went through the work of factoring $c$.

Comment: Thanks for your first paragraph - I understand it, that was sloppy of me.  As for your second paragraph, thank you! I should have had the initiative to try a little test case, which I've now done.  For instance:

(1)  6 = 2 X 3
(2) 15 = 3 X 5
(3)  6 + 15 = 21
(4)  21 = 3 X 7

Although 2 is a prime factor of 6, and 5 is a prime factor of 15, neither 2 nor 5 are prime factors of 21.  And 7, which is a prime factor of 21, isn't a prime factor of either 6 or 15.  So, as you say, the prime factors of a and b don't tell one much (anything, even?) about the prime factors of c.

Thank you!